# Illegal division by zero when running perl script

Tags: perl

I am running the following Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$file1 = $ARGV[0];

system("analyze $file1 M | grep Moments -A 4 > inertia.dat");

open(INFILE, "inertia.dat") or die "Can't open file: $!";

$line = <INFILE>;
$line = <INFILE>;
$line = <INFILE>;
$line = <INFILE>;
$line = <INFILE>;

$I1 = substr($line,16,12);
$line = <INFILE>;
$I2  = substr($line,16,12);
$line = <INFILE>;
$I3  = substr($line,16,12);
$line = <INFILE>;    

if (($I1>$I2) && ($I1>$I3)) {$I1 = <Imax>;}
if (($I2>$I1) && ($I2>$I3)) {$I2 = <Imax>;}
if (($I3>$I1) && ($I31>$I2)) {$I3 = <Imax>;}
if (($I1<$I2) && ($I1<$I3)) {$I1 = <Imin>;}
if (($I2<$I1) && ($I2<$I3)) {$I2 = <Imin>;}
if (($I3<$I1) && ($I3<$I2)) {$I3 =<Imin>;}

$delta = ((<Imax>)-(<Imin>))/(<Imax>);
print "$I1 $I2 $I3\n";

close INFILE;
```

When I run the file, I get "Illegal division by zero at line 45"

Line 45 is

```
$delta = ((<Imax>)-(<Imin>))/(<Imax>);
```

An example of the inertia.dat file is:

Moments of Inertia and Principal Axes :

```
         Moments (amu Ang^2)          X-, Y- and Z-Components of Axes

             102508.853              0.096680    0.000809   -0.995315
             114243.409              0.393377   -0.918614    0.037464
             118155.898             -0.914280   -0.395156   -0.089130
```

Answer (score 7):

First, `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of every single perl script you ever write. This will tell you about the second issue:

Second, you are attempting to read from filehandles named `Imax` and `Imin`, so of course you're getting a divide-by-zero (or rather, undefined that is getting cast to zero in this case). These filehandles do not exist in your script.